# Let $f(x)=1$ if $x=0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x>0$. Show that $f$ is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Let $f(x)=1$ if $x=0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x>0$. Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. I think for everyone this question is really basic, but I'm just training myself on proving the integrability of functions. Certainly, there are easiests ways to prove the statement, but I would like to prove it considering upper and lower Darboux sums. So, I would just like to know if my approach is correct, please x)

By definition, $f$ is integrable iff. $\exists$ a subdivision $\sigma$: $\overline{S}_{\sigma}(f)<\underline{S}_{\sigma}(f)+\epsilon \ \forall \epsilon>0$.

First, I remark that for all subdivisions, the lower Darboux sum is equal to $0$. So, we have to show that $\overline{S}_{\sigma}(f)<\epsilon \ \forall \epsilon>0$.

Then, consider $0<\epsilon<2$, the intervals $[0,\epsilon/2]$ and $(\epsilon/2,1]$ and two first terms of partition $x_0=0,x_1=\epsilon/2...$ We don't consider the rest of partition, as the upper Darboux sum is trivially $0$ whatever the partition on the interval $(\epsilon/2,1]$.

Thus, $\overline{S}_{\sigma}(f)=\sum_{i=0}^{0}1\cdot (\epsilon/2-0)+0<\epsilon$.

We conclude then that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is Ok. You could simplify by considering $\epsilon$ instead of $\epsilon/2$ which is not necessary here.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thank you very much for your feedback!)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few problems with your approach: when you write that you have to show that$$\overline{S_\sigma}<\varepsilon\ \forall\varepsilon>0,\tag1$$you don't tell was which partition $\sigma$ is, but then you acto as if it was a concrete partition. For instance, how do you know that $\frac\varepsilon2$ belongs to the partition. Besides, what you need to prove is that, for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is some partition $\sigma$ such that $\overline{S_\sigma}<\varepsilon$, which is *not* the same thing as $(1)$. And it is easy to do: just take $\sigma=\left\{0,\frac\varepsilon2,1\right\}$, if $\frac\varepsilon2<1$; otherwise, $\sigma=\{0,1\}$ will do.

Comment: But in the beginning I wrote that: $\exists$ partition $\sigma $... And then I just explicited 2 first terms of the partition, as the other terms it could be watever we want as it will always be equal to $0$ (in the upper Darboux sum)

Comment: *Where* did you write “$\exists$ partition $\sigma$”?

Comment: In the beginning of the post. I just have one question on your proposed partition $\sigma=\{0,1\}$: How can we show that the upper Darboux sum is $< \epsilon \ \forall \epsilon >0$? The upper Darboux sum for this partition would be equal to $1$. Or do I miss something? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, you are **not** supposed to prove that there is an upper Darboux sum smaller than $\varepsilon$ $\forall\varepsilon>0$. It's the other way around: for all $\varepsilon>0$, you are supposed to prove that there is an upper Darboux sum smaller than $\varepsilon$. And if $\varepsilon>1$, I just take $\sigma=\{0,1\}$. Otherwise, I take $\left\{0,\frac\varepsilon2,1\right\}$.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!

Comment: I just have one more question,please, to be sure that I understood well. What your tried to tell, is that $\epsilon$ depends on partition, so for each partition, there is a “bound” for $\epsilon$ (I.e it doesn’t have to works for every epsilon)

Comment: No. It's the partition that depends on $\varepsilon$. And this is the third time that I tell you this.

Comment: So to make proof complete, I have to show that there is a partition for $0<\epsilon<2$ and for $\epsilon>1$? Or it is necessary to show only for one of them? If yes, why? I’m really sorry for this kind of questions, but I just want to understand where I’m wrong. Thank you very much for bearing me. Edit: but if I show for the first condition, it would be clearly true for each $\epsilon>1$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. It is enough to do it for small values of $\varepsilon$ (for instance, only for those that belong to $(0,2)$, as you wrote) and then it will be automatically true that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there will be a partition $\sigma$ such that $\overline{S_\sigma}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Alright, thank you! But If I show the integrability with partition $\sigma=\{0,1\}$ for $\epsilon>1$, then the proof is not complete as we don’t know (not shown) if there is a partition for $\epsilon<1$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120175/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-daniil).

Comment: +1 for the answer as well discussion in comments / chat.